# About the problems of using the new operator inside a class that'll be Unit-Tested

Tags: c#, java, unit-testing, oop, immutability

### Intro

Currently I have something of the form:

```
Tetris class ---> FallingPiece class ----> Piece class
```

A `Piece` can be a `Square`, a `T`, etc. It has info about its shape and the shapes of its rotations, its size, etc.

The `FallingPiece` class basically contains an attribute with a reference to a `Piece` (the currently falling piece in the Tetris game) and will probably have its current `(x, y)` location and its color.

My initial design was to have something of the form:

```
class Tetris {
    private IPieceGenerator pieceGenerator;
    private FallingPiece fallingPiece;
    ...

    public Tetris(IPieceGenerator pieceGenerator) {
        this.pieceGenerator = pieceGenerator;
        ...
    }

    private void someMethodThatNeedsAFallingPiece() {
        if (fallingPiece == null) {
            Piece piece = pieceGenerator.Generate();
            fallingPiece = new FallingPiece(piece);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

which of course has the problem that if I later want to Unit-Test my Tetris class and to know in which `(x, y)` location of the board my current `FallingPiece` is, I can't. I remember seeing this "problem" exposed in the fabulous [Misko Hevery's The Clean Code Talks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w) .

### The first problem

seems to be that as I'm giving the `Tetris` class the responsability of creating `FallingPiece` objects, I can't then have a reference to them (I have passed through constructor injection a `Piece` Factory, not `FallingPiece` Factory!).

Now, I can see at least 2 ways to solve this:

1. I could just define an `internal`(C#)/`package-protected`(Java) getter for the `FallingPiece` attribute, so I can easily test it. This might seem harmless, but I don't find it too elegant.
2. I could instead of passing it a `Piece` Factory, pass a `FallingPiece` Factory. I could then control which objects would be returned by the Factory and access them through it. What do you guys think of this way? Is it commonly used?

Is there any other way of solving this?

### There is a second problem

related to fact that I've originally implemented a `FallingPiece` to be an immutable type. This means that every time I want to update the `FallingPiece`'s position on the `Tetris` board, for example, I'll have to create a new `FallingPiece` instance and the attribute on Tetris will now point to a new `FallingPiece`. Which can be a big problem if I want, for example, to have access to the `FallingPiece` reference through a `FallingPieceFactory` that is passed to the `Tetris` class. It appears to me that immutable data types can be if misused a lot of headache when trying to test classes, right? Or is this a bad use of an immutable datatype, in the first place?

Thanks

Comment: Can I see an ideal test case (the kind you'd like to write if you had no problems) ? Focus on the behavior and expected side effects/interactions. I may be wrong, but can't you drive the next FallingPiece by generating a dummy piece from a mock PieceFactory?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant.  Could you be a bit more clear?

Comment: Are you using SCM. If Not you might want to check out Github.com. That way we can look at your code from there.

Answer (score 1):

Possiblle solution:

1. Instead of wiring implementations together, use interfaces.
2. Intruduce a generator for creating FallingPiece

This way you can test everything using mock objects for your interfaces. change visibility of someMethodThatNeedsAFallingPiece to protected to access it in your test case or call it using reflection (evil).

```
public class Tetris {

    private IPieceGenerator pieceGenerator;
    private IFallingPiece fallingPiece;
    private IFallingPieceGenerator fallingPieceGenerator;

    public Tetris(IPieceGenerator pieceGenerator, IFallingPieceGenerator fallingPieceGenerator) {
      this.pieceGenerator = pieceGenerator;
      this.fallingPieceGenerator = fallingPieceGenerator;

    }

    protected void someMethodThatNeedsAFallingPiece() {
      if (fallingPiece == null) {
          IPiece piece = pieceGenerator.Generate();
          fallingPiece = fallingPieceGenerator.generate(piece);
      }

    }

}
```

Here's your unit test:

```
public class TetrisTest {

    private IPieceGenerator pieceGeneratorMock;

    private IFallingPieceGenerator fallingPieceGeneratorMock;

    private IFallingPiece fallingPieceMock;

    private IPiece pieceMock;

    private Tetris tetris;



    @Before
    public void init() {
      this.pieceGeneratorMock = EasyMock.createMock(IPieceGenerator.class);
      this.fallingPieceGeneratorMock = EasyMock.createMock(IFallingPieceGenerator.class);
      this.fallingPieceMock = EasyMock.createMock(IFallingPiece.class);
      this.pieceMock = EasyMock.createMock(IPiece.class);
      this.tetris = new Tetris(pieceGeneratorMock, fallingPieceGeneratorMock);



    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethodThatNeedsAFallingPiece() {
      expect(pieceGeneratorMock.Generate()).andReturn(pieceMock);
      expect(fallingPieceGeneratorMock.generate(pieceMock)).andReturn(fallingPieceMock);
      replay(fallingPieceMock, fallingPieceGeneratorMock, pieceGeneratorMock, pieceMock);

      tetris.someMethodThatNeedsAFallingPiece();

      verify(fallingPieceMock, fallingPieceGeneratorMock, pieceGeneratorMock, pieceMock);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would inject only a `FallingPieceFactory` to reduce the coupling of `Tetris` to other classes. It looks like that it havn't to know about the `PieceFactory` AND the `FallingPieceFactory`.

I would orientate the testing on the usage of the `Tetris` class. Your method must have an observable effect. How is it used? Is there a class that uses the data of `Tetris` to paint the game field? Then there would be a getter anyway. Or is the painting called by the `Tetris` class? Then it have to had a reference to the responsible class and you can inject and observe (possible mock) this painting class.

Regarding immutibility: I never experienced any problems with testing immutable objects. If `FallingPiece` is a good candidate to be immutable seems questionable as the main purpose seems to be fall down (means: change its position).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the `Tetris` object is doing to much:

```
protected void someMethodThatNeedsAFallingPiece() {
  if (fallingPiece == null) {
      IPiece piece = pieceGenerator.Generate();
      fallingPiece = fallingPieceGenerator.generate(piece);
  }
}
```

This method has too many reponsibilities.

1. Logic to validate non-null `fallingPiece`.
2. Generate `piece`.
3. Generate new `fallingPiece`.

You should be following the 'Last Possible Moment of Decision`. Get rid of all that. **KISS**.

Try this:

```
protected void someMethodThatNeedsAFallingPiece() {
  fallingPiece = pieceModel.getFallingPiece();
}
```

Push that logic into the `pieceModel`

Comment: Actually that's what I'm trying to accomplish.